# How to iterate an Javascript Object from the inside out

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iteration, javascript-objects

I have the following Javascript Object that I would like to iterate from the innermost objects as I come out. If an inner object is an array of integers and Javascript objects, we go through the Javascript Objects first, then the integers.

How can I go about this?

Thank you all in advance.

I would like this kind of iteration procedure:

> **109**[107] -> **109**[1] -> **109**[0] -> [3] -> [6] -> ......

The Javascript Object:

```
[
    97,
    {
      '109': [ 
        98,  99, 
        '107': [ 100, 101, 102 ]
      ]
    },
    110,
    {'386': [103, 105, 106 ]},
    387,
    388,
    { '671': 104 },
    672
  ]
```

**EDIT**

I meant Javascript Object, not JSON Array.

Comment: That is invalid JSON, isn't it? You cannot use property-syntax inside an array.

Comment: That's not a "JSON Array", nor "JSON Objects". [There's no such thing](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), since JSON is a text format. What you have there is an array containing arrays and objects. Try searching without including the word "JSON" and you may find more matches.

Comment: You need to explain a little better please exactly how you want to get from your sample input to the desired output, along with some desired output.

Comment: This (`'109': [ 98,  99, '107': [ 100, 101, 102 ]]`) is still invalid syntax

Comment: Why is your data in this format? It seems odd to have such a mixture of numbers and Objects and Objects with Arrays. I would normalise your data before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

**Impossible**. There is no bottom to top reference in this data structure; which means items don't store a "parent" reference to able you iterate backward (e.g. there is only one reference exists to  access`[ 100, 101, 102 ]`, and it is `array[1]['109'][2]`); hence the only way is to go from top to bottom;

you should make your own data structure to support that ( e.g. using a combination of [two-way link list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) and arrays .. )

---

Imagine you have array of "box"es (Frustration gift box), and each box may or may not contain smaller boxes, the only way to understand if a box contains a smaller box or not is to unwrap the parent box and see what is inside it. and the same for the smaller box inside box inside the parent, you have to open it until you reach the gift.

now imagine you have 10 Frustration gift boxes and you have no idea whats inside them you until had opened them all; you 'd unwrapped every box, all the boxes are now exposed and you know exactly how many smaller boxes are in every box and where are the gifts.
here is the interesting part, now you are asking, how to could I access the gifts first, and without opening all the boxes first. you can't since it not intended to be reached from inner most box; you have to do it the hard way and go through until you find the gift. 
[image]

---

By the way recursive approach seems a good fit for your need, you have to first expose everything, then store parent references then iterate backwards. doesn't sound efficient by the way. I suggest try another approach than iterating from bottom to top;

Comment: FYI: images usually need attribution if they were not taken by you. This is a friendly warning, because some mods delete such posts. Either add the copyright notice who is the author of the picture or remove it from your post.